# How to update cached data on click in rtk query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to mutate the data received from below endpoint after an onClick from a screen using **updateQueryData** or is there any other better way to achieve mutation on the cached data.

```
export const exampleCreateApi = createApi({
 reducerPath: 'exampleApi',
 baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl : 'https://www.example.com/api'}),
 endpoints: (builder) => ({
    characters: builder.query<Character[], void>({
        query: () => '/characters',
        transformResponse: (response: Character[]) => {
            return response.map(item => ({...item, isFavourite: false }))
        },

    }),
```

Comment: checkout this link for manually update the cache https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates